# iMacros - TAG specific element with XPATH

Tags: html, xpath, tags, imacros, scrape

and thank you in advance for taking a minute of your valuable time to solve this puzzle and educate me on the topic.

(please forgive my terminology)

I am using the following code in iMacros for Firefox to select an element on the site, which works fine, as long as the element exists and is in the same order.

```
TAG XPATH=".//*[@id='contacts']/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Which in this case would result in "New York, NY"

From:

```
<div id="contacts" class="article expanding_group">
<div class="article-header">
<!-- Public Company = Block. Public Name/Title = Restricted. -->
<ul class="list">
<li class="list_item">
<div class="list_item_content contact-detail">
<div class="edit expanded">
<ul>
<li class="name"> New York, NY </li>
<li class=" ellipsis">
<a href="http://www.a24films.com" target="_blank">http://www.a24films.com</a>
</li>
<li class="info ">
+1 646 568 6015
<span class="attributes">phone</span>
</li>
<li class="info ellipsis">
<a href="mailto:info@a24films.com" data-linkpa="offsite-contact--email">info@a24films.com</a>
</li>
<li class="address ">601 West 26th Street</li>
<li class="address ">Suite 1740</li>
<li class="address "> New York, NY 10001 </li>
<li class="address ">USA</li>
<li class="address ">
</ul>
</div>
```

However, if the field is missing, it will skip to the next field which will, in essence, result in data being inserted into the incorrect row.

E.g. if I am expecting columns "name, phone, address", and it is missing phone, it will result in "name, address, blank".

I can see it I want only when list item 1's class="name", so my question is: is there a way to specify that I want the list item number 1 that contains "name" in class?

I have tried a variation of strings to no avail, but I woulf imaging something like this is possible:

```
TAG XPATH=".//*[@id='contacts']/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]/name" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Thank you for your time,

Reinaldo

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
TAG XPATH=".//*[@id='contacts']/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[@class='name'][1]" EXTRACT=TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath:
`.//*[@id='contacts']//li[@class='name'][1]`

I don't think @Shugar's code will work.